# Efficient array value replacement

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of values in PHP looking something like this:

```
$test = array (  
    array( 'val' => 2, 'color' => 'blue' ),  
    array( 'val' => 5, 'color' => 'green' ),  
);
```

I want to go through all elements of `$test` and add `1` to all `val` indices.  Now I realize a `foreach` loop could work, but I am looking for something a little more efficient. The array will potentially have 10's of thousands of elements and hundreds of sub-elements.

I am wondering if there is some type of way that PHP can go through and modify just that index throughout the entire array, based on the argument that I set.

Comment: `table`...`columns`,  so are you working with SQL or PHP arrays here?

Comment: I am working with PHP as I stated in the question.  I am simply calling it a table because it is easier to visualize a table with many columns and you are editing a column throughout all data points.  A 2d array is essentially just a simplified table

Comment: You have not told why `foreach` isn't efficient. Who says that?

Comment: perhaps because it reinvents the wheel. Doing something simple for each collumn of an array can be done with array_walk or array_map.

Comment: I do not think that foreach would be inefficient speed wise, I should have clarified that I want something cleaner programming wise. I may need to do this many times so it is worth it to me to find out if php already has such functionality before I build my own, no point in reinventing what has already been made

Comment: Foreach is not re-inventing anything, it offers access to iteration which offers the same amount of re-usability as let's say `array_map`, with the benefit that the code is more expressive. So as long as you only have a problem in writing code but not much of specification and actual need, I find it rather broad that you ask such a question.

Comment: I know that foreach does not mean RIW but in that case, perhaps, it is. He only wants to increments 1 variable and no more. It is not very expressif to do
    `<?php foreach($myArray as &$value){
    $value['val']++;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array_walk and a closure to do it

```
array_walk($yourArray,function(&$col){$col['val']++});
```